# No Dependent passport number on New Zealand tourist visa

Tags: visas, new-zealand

i am primary applicant for NZ tourist visa. My husband is accompanying me. We have our names and date of birth on our NZ visa but only primary applicant passport number.

Is that correct?

Comment: What nationality are you both?

Comment: @RoryAlsop does it make any difference?

Comment: It usually does

Comment: Exactly where in which field on _your_ visa does your husband's name appear?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.